# Unable to connect to MySQL database but able to connect to server

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, wamp

I am just using a basic code to connect to my Mysql database. I am able to connect to my server but not database. using sqlyog:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("project",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select project");

    $sql = "SELECT image_small FROM images";
    mysql_query($sql,$selected);

    while($row=extract_row($sql))
    {
        echo $row['image_small'];
    } 
?>
```

Comment: does the database ``project`` exists?

Answer (score 2):

where is password of database? [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-connect.php) should be used as:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
```

otherwise it will be the default password that will be used

Comment: what if there is no password?

Comment: if no password, just send blank as password, eg ''

Comment: if no password, there is `ini_get("mysql.default_password")`

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong here.
1. Your have a blank password for the root user in your database.
2. You're using mysql_* which everybody know is subject to many hasck.
3. You're trying to "extract" a row from your SQL query.

Use PDO:

```
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project","root","root_password");
$sql = "SELECT image_small FROM images";
foreach($DB->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  echo $row['image_small'];
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\wamp\www\project\ex.php on line 3
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\project\ex.php on line 3

Comment: Honestly, you should not connect as root.  Go into MySQL and add a user specific to your "Project" database.  Give that user a valid password and connect using the new user credentials.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

try to connect using the following statement

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("project");
```

// i think you have to provide password in here mysql_connect($hostname, $username,$password);
since it is localhost and user is root you could use like this

```
 mysql_connect($hostname, $username,"");
```